# Delete character in sublist

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have a list of sublists in the following format:

```
[['1023869', '-0.137869328454', '0.318039373746', '1.243\n'], ['1023870', '-0.121434633793', '0.324670024328', '1.243\n']]
```

I want to delete "\n" from the last element in the sublist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just mutable last element in given list.

```
for subList in alist:
  subList[-1] = subList[-1][:-1]
```

```
>>> alist
>>> [['1023869', '-0.137869328454', '0.318039373746', '1.243'], ['1023870', '-0.121434633793', '0.324670024328', '1.243']]
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't change?

Comment: It does changed.

Comment: @lavendermp Ah yeah sorry, wasn't paying attention

Comment: @MisterMiyagi True, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension with `rstrip`:

```
[sublist[:-1] + [sublist[-1].rstrip()] for sublist in lst]
```

---

```
[['1023869', '-0.137869328454', '0.318039373746', '1.243'], 
 ['1023870', '-0.121434633793', '0.324670024328', '1.243']]
```

Comment: Hmm this does not seem to work for me :-(

Comment: @AsbjoernLund What's your error/output